# Change the title of an IBAction from another IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm wondering how to call an `IBAction` from another `IBAction`.
What I want to do is when I touch a button on `previousPage`, the title of the `nextPage` button to change.
In other words I have these `IBActions`:

```
- (IBAction)nextPageButtonItemPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
  ...
}

- (IBAction)previousParageButtonItemPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
  //This is what i want to do
  [self nextPageButtonItemPressed:sender.title = @"Next Page"];
}
```

I have also created an `IBOutlet` of `previousPage`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *nextPageOutlet;
```

But I can't find the way to do this.

P.S. The `nextPage` is a button in `UIToolbar`.

Comment: These are "methods". `IBAction` is just a semantic to tell Interface Builder that a method can be connected with an action.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Yes I understand but I thought that as I can write inside a method this sender.title = @"bla bla"; if i can call sender for other method. Is any way to do this?

Comment: Using the `sender` variable, you can change only the title of the button that triggered the method call. If you need to change both titles, you will need to set properties.

Comment: It's possible to this in a more complicated way if you use an IBOutletCollection of UIButtons, then iterate through them to find out which one isn't sender but it's a lot more easier/concise to just use a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to have your `UIButton` as an `IBOutlet` property.

So something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *previousButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *nextButton;


- (IBAction)nextPageButtonItemPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
  ...
}

- (IBAction)previousPageButtonItemPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
  self.nextButton.title = @"Next Page"; 
}
```

Comment: It was so easy! I had create the Outlet for UIToolbar instead of UIBarButtonItem. Thanks a lot LuricaPanda! I create this on the header file
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *nextPageBarButtonItemOutlet;
And I add your code "self.nextPageBarButtonItemOutlet.title = @"Next Page";" to the method I want!